# This circuit keeps tripping - why?

Tags: switch

I'm extending a switch leg and running into an over-current situation I don't understand.  I'm attaching my best Paint art to show you how the circuit is planned.  The red legs from the right hand switch to the switched portions of the split receptacles are producing a short.  I tested each leg of the switched (red) lines and found no shorts between red, black, white and ground.

[image]

Comment: 1 - Pictures! Please upload pictures of each receptacle and switch and junction box showing all wires; 2 - Are you sure both receptacles have the hot-side tab removed?

Comment: the neutral and hot should not connect to the same side of the plug

Comment: both duplex plugs should be wired the same, not a mirror image of each other

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Slow down there and be careful of internet electricians! A switch leg has power coming to a switch on the white it is not a neutral. The switched hot goes out on the black. This is the leading mistake for internet only and diy electricians. If things worked and you added or modified a switch leg you probably have tied the switch leg hot to neutral someplace. The white is supposed to be re identified as a hot at both ends but this is often overlooked or the tape was removed. To find the source of the short you need a volt meter or good non contact volt meter and you have to identify the hots